# Cypress: cy.task vs cy.request for interacting with backend by API?

Tags: node.js, request, automated-tests, cypress

I want to set the app in a preconditioned state (before testing) by making HTTP requests to the backend by exposed API. I need to make a series of HTTP requests like creating an account, uploading a file, executing some processes, etc. Some of the requests return some data in the response body which I need to pass to the next requests. I need the requests to be run sequentially so one request needs to be finished in order to execute the next one.

Should I use cy.request() for that or maybe cy.task() and an external tool like axios to make HTTP requests?

I found an article:  https://spin.atomicobject.com/2021/07/30/cypress-tasks-vs-commands/
where there is written:

> If you need to run a promise or interact with your backend, go with a task. Remember: Commands are not promises. If you are interacting with the DOM and making assertions, go with a command.

So according to it, it's advised to go with cy.task when interacting with backend. But why?
What are the benefits of making API calls using cy.tasks instead of making them by cy.request?

I tried to approach this by cy.task() and axios, which let me assign response data to variables and pass them to the next requests but it made debugging the HTTP requests harder because the requests are being executed in a separate node process outside of the cypress browser context so I need to console.log() the requests to see if they are correct or to see the response message.

Comment: One thing to note for using `cy.request()` is exposing the API response to your test for assertions or for UI checks. We use this to create data for our tests and also check the status of each API to narrow down root causes for failures. I'm sure this can be done with `cy.task()` or using axios, but might be a bit more work to expose the data to your tests.

Comment: Your questions are too opened ended. We have no clue what problem you're trying to solve. What are you doing with this backend API? Are you seeding an environment? Do you need to assert data that comes back from the API? There is no one size fits all solution to this. Please update your question with specifics.

Comment: But can you say what problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: ***so one request needs to be finished in order to execute the next one*** - you mean sequentially, not asynchronously. All HTTP calls are asynchronous.

Answer (score 4):

The article is only partially correct.

You cannot `await cy.request()`, but it's ***not necessary*** to use `cy.task()` to handle `axios` async/await.

Try this in your test:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

it('handles axios calls in the browser', async () => {

  const result = await axios.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'
  });

  const expectedObject = {userId: 1, id: 1, title: 'delectus aut autem', completed: false}

  expect(result.status).to.eq(200); 
  expect(result.data).to.deep.eq(expectedObject)     // ✅ passes
})
```

---

#### Intercepting

Even better, you can remove the async/await and use the `cy.intercept()` API with axios calls

```js
import axios from 'axios';

it('uses cy.intercept() with axios calls', () => {

  cy.intercept('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').as('fetch')

  axios.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'
  });

  const expectedObject = {userId: 1, id: 1, title: 'delectus aut autem', completed: false}

  cy.wait('@fetch')
    .its('response.body')
    .should('deep.eq', expectedObject)               // ✅ passes
})
```

which is something you cannot do with `cy.request()`

```js
it('intercepts cy.request() calls', () => {

  cy.intercept('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').as('fetch')

  cy.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'
  });

  const expectedObject = {userId: 1, id: 1, title: 'delectus aut autem', completed: false}

  cy.wait('@fetch')
    .its('response.body')
    .should('deep.eq', expectedObject)               // ❌ fails
})
```

#### In Summary

`cy.request()` is designed not to interact with the `cy.intercept()` API, so you can issue requests from the test and not interfere with code that should only be monitoring requests issuing from the app under test.

If you use `axios` to make the requests, you run the risk of unexpected results from your `cy.intercept()` network listeners.

Comment: thank you for the answer @Fody. Unfortunately, it doesn't answer my question. The question I ask is: To interact with the backend by the HTTP requests should I go with cy.request (process in the browser) or cy.task (node process)? What is more convenient or advised and why?

Comment: I just illustrate the technical differences between the two methods. As said in the comments, ***your questions are too opened ended. We have no clue what problem you're trying to solve***. It's better if you actually understand how each works and think about how to apply, rather just than asking for an opinion.